# About Customized SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

I inflate layer on the main frame and there is a `ScrollView`.
I want to draw a large image that can move left, right, top, and down on the screen.
So, I described this with a `SurfaceView` that I customized and `addView` to `ScrollView`,
but the Image that I want doesn't show. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a need to use a SurfaceView in this case. SurfaceViews are typically used for things like Camera preview, Video playback. And there's GLSurfaceView for opengl drawing.

If you are procedurally creating the large image that you want to display, for example, via Canvas.draw methods, then you can probably simple create a custom View subclass and override onDraw (and possibly onMeasure).

Or, if you are loading a large image from disk or as a resource, just use an ImageView.

Comment: The large image is not simple image.
I want draw complex animation in that area. (such as game play)

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, a simple View subclass should be perfect then. You override onDraw, and then draw whatever you want onto the Canvas that you get passed as a parameter. Just keep in mind you'll also want to override onMeasure, to set the measured size of the view to be however big you want it.